# Force a device to give up its IP address?

Tags: network, linux, ip, arp

Expanding to a previous question where I asked if it would be possible to redirect traffic on a port from another device to my local device, if a PC on my network (device A) has the IP address 192.168.1.2, would it be possible for another PC (device B) that has an IP address 192.168.1.3 to force-use the IP address 192.168.1.2 in a way that causes device A to lose network access through that IP? If yes, how would that be possible or how can I prevent this type of attack?

For testing, I tried to use the IP 192.168.1.2 on 2 devices on the same network with ARP checking disabled. Only device A was responding, but I'm not sure if there is a type of attack that can cause device A to stop responding and I wasn't able to find this information online, so any answer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it wired or wireless?

Comment: @user2497 Mostly wireless, but device A was wired while device B was wireless when I did the test. I do not think it would make a difference, but I can connect both of them to wireless/wired.

Answer (score 1):

This would be an "attack" that would prevent only devices that don't know the MAC address/IP correspondence to talk to Device A. Under normal circumstances they would have the MAC address of Device A in their ARP cache.

If however this cache expires or a new device is connected to the LAN (the same broadcast domain) then the ARP request "who has 192.168.1.2" would be answered by two different machines. Quoting from [Networking Basics: How ARP Works](https://www.tummy.com/articles/networking-basics-how-arp-works/):

> In the case where multiple machines have the same IP address, you may
>   get multiple responses. The one that gets placed in the ARP table can
>   vary depending on the networking implementation, how busy hosts are,
>   and how quickly they respond, etc...

Your concern is unavailability of Device A but another thing that can happen is for an attacker to be a man-in-the-middle: Inform you Device A that he has the IP of the gateway and inform the gateway that he has the IP of Device A. He will thus make all traffic to and from Device A pass from the eavesdropping system in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

This question is asking about forcing a client to release its IP address. Yes, if it is a wifi network you can cause the device to be dropped, and for wired you can drop the host from the network as well.  But to answer the question about forcing a client to give up its IP, without completely dropping it, would be possible through DHCP as outlined in rfc3203 by sending the client a FORCERENEW:

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3203.txt

That being said, you would be depending on all the clients to actually obey, and not all do. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/1bb50932-29bc-4446-a1a4-081037207f36/dhcp-forcerenew-message?forum=winserverNIS

Answer (score 0):

You can boot a client from a wireless network thus:
`iwpriv wlanX kickmac 00:de:ad:be:ef:01`.
http://madwifi-project.org/wiki/UserDocs/iwpriv
The IP will be available for a moment until reconnect. Look into isc-dhcpd as well.

Comment: Sorry, this may be technically correct but requires a lot of specialized explanation to make sense...

Comment: @Georgios It requires 'man iwpriv'.

Comment: Most worth noting is that this, at intervals of say 0.3 seconds, will entirely prevent a station from becoming associated and obtaining a DHCP lease.